# C++ in batch programming

Tags: c++, batch-file

I'm just wondering if I can use C++ in batch scripts for a method of a counter? Sorry if I used the wrong terminology for this I'm relitivly new to this language

New: My friends got me into batch scripts and I wanted to mess around with one of them so, I'm in the process of writing a file that starts itself 10 time before looping again. I want my script to increase a variable to 20 then have it kill all instances of ot and then without the user knowing shutdown the computer after 2 minutes. I correctly coded the loop, the kill-all, and the shutdown. I know I will need to use an if/else statement but I don't know how to code the variable amd how to increase it and check value of variable.

Comment: Do you want to know if you can call a program made with C++ in a batch file or if you can use C++ syntax in a batch file to write the batch file?

Comment: Not nearly enough detail to understand what you mean.

Comment: you can embed `c#`,`visual basic`,`powershell`,`jscript.net`,`jscript`,`vbscript` into batch file. These languages come installed by default in windows , but there's no `c++` compiler. If you install `visual studio` there's a neat way to embed `c++` code through msbuild and its inline tasks.

Comment: @npocmaka: I'm pretty sure the C# compiler doesn't come installed. The .Net runtime does, however.

Comment: @MSalters - check in this folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.XXX`   - there are three compilers - `jsc.exe` , `vbc.exe` ,`csc.exe`  - they come installed by default since Windows Vista (though vista comes with .net 3.5). Try with virtualbox image if you don't believe me :)

Answer (score 2):

A batch file can run programs written in C++ and other languages.

Counting in a batch file is a bit tricky due to the way that batch file commands are processed, namely via text substitution. The `set /a` command might be what you're looking for. Or maybe `for /L`.

Type `/?` after a standard Windows command to get a short help text for that command, e.g. `set /?`.